# SQL remove duplicate rows when counting

Tags: sql

I have a select statement using count and since I am counting the rows instead of returning them how do I make sure that I do not get a duplicate value on a column?

For Example

```
_table_
fName     someField
Eric       data
Kyle       mdata
Eric       emdata
Andrew     todata
```

I want the count to be 3 because Eric is duplicated, is there a way to do that? My select is:

```
Select Count(*) From _table_ INTO :var
```

Thanks,

Comment: grouping them wont remove the duplicates will it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT fName) From _table_ INTO :var
```

It will count number of distinct elements from `fName` column.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the Job `Select Count(distinct fnmae) From _table_ INTO :var`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT fName) From _table_ INTO :var
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select the count of DISTINCT first names:

```
declare @table table (fname varchar(20), someField varchar(20))
insert into @table (fname, someField)
select 'Eric', 'data'
union select 'Kyle', 'mdata'
union select 'Eric', 'emdata'
union select 'Andrew', 'todata'

-- returns 4, because there are 4 rows in the table
select count(*) from @table     

-- returns 3, because there are 3 rows with distinct first names
select count(*) from (select distinct fname from @table) firstNames
```